# Getting rid of hard wire for dishwasher

Tags: electrical, dishwasher

I'm installing a new dishwasher.  I would like to go with a plug and outlet even though the old one was hardwired into the house.  What do I do to take care of the hardwire line?

Comment: But why? Outlets are for conveniently plugging in & unplugging things, anything else you'll regularly be using in the wallspace behind a dishwasher permanently installed? Could you even reach it? It's only like 4 screws to attach the power wire anyway

Comment: Be sure to check whether your new dishwasher requires a 20A power supply. If it does, you would need to use a 20A receptacle (on a 20A circuit), or just stick with hard wiring it. Another advantage of hard wiring it is that it will ensure that the dishwasher is the only appliance on the circuit, which it should be.

Answer (score 10):

Purchase an appliance cord, at least 6' long. Route the power cable from the house for the dishwasher into the the under sink space.  Install a electrical box and conventional receptacle on this power line.  Fix it to the back wall of the sink base.  Route the cord from the dish washer into the sink base together with the water lines. Plug this cord into the new receptacle. P.

Comment: I would NOT want an electrical plug/receptacle under my sink... Sinks leak all the time, especially when working on the faucet/trap. I think it's even against many building codes, maybe a good way to void your house insurance too. Otherwise a good idea, just put the plug somewhere else. Or use a longer cord & plug the dishwasher in anywhere

Comment: Electrical receptacles are installed under sinks for dishwashers, garbage disposals and instant hot water heaters all the time. If local code or the equipment calls for it, you install a GFCI. Proper grounding is essential.

Comment: Outlets under the sink cabinet or behind the dish washer are 100% code compliant. The cord length as listed by the NEC for a dishwasher is 3feet to 6.5 feet code ref 422.16. I have never seen a 20 amp residential dishwasher.

Answer (score 4):

The hardwired line could be used to feed the receptacle. No point to running a new circuit if that one is an individual circuit.

Regardless of whether you use a receptacle or not, the outlets (not receptacles) on the circuit supplying the dishwasher are now required to be protected by GFCI.

From the 2014 and 2017 National Electrical Code:

> **210.8(D) Kitchen Dishwasher Branch Circuit.** GFCI protection shall be provided for outlets that supply dishwashers installed in dwelling unit locations.

So, you can either buy a GFCI receptacle (cheaper solution) or a GFCI breaker for the circuit that it is connected to.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: The GFCI would be required for new construction but not just replacing a dishwasher.

Comment: @EdBeal true enough unless it is a kitchen remodel that will be inspected. The inspector may require the upgrade then.

Comment: Current code requires 4 wire outlet for ranges but not required to replace these unless walls are open, the OP only wants to eliminate a hard wire, an old work box in the wall or surface mount at the hole the wire comes out and it still may be legal without a GFCI, I hard wire because my state did not adopt 210.9.d and in the past gfci's were not required on hard wired appliances.